# Копирование директории на удаленный хост с помощью Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

Добрый день! Я пытаюсь скопировать директорию на удаленный хост. Для этого я написал playbook. Как правильно указать путь к директории которую я хочу скопировать и есть ли различия в копирования конкретного файла и целой директории?

playbook выглядит так:

```
---
- hosts: vhosts

  tasks:

    - name: Push dir
    copy: src=/home/goiath/k-systemd dest=/tmp
```

выполняю команду так: "ansible-playbook playbooks/copy_file.yml --ask-sudo-pass"

Ошибка с параметром -vvvv:

```
fatal: [k4-test-1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! failed 
to transfer file to /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-
1498045321.5-48674671838555/source:\nsftp> put '/home/goliath/k-
systemd/annotation\n\nOpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  
1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data 
/etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying 
options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: 
fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master 
version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 
local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: 
entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 1821\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1: 
mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug2: Remote 
version: 3\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension \"posix-
rename@openssh.com\" revision 1\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension 
\"statvfs@openssh.com\" revision 2\r\ndebug2: Server supports 
extension \"fstatvfs@openssh.com\" revision 2\r\ndebug2: Server 
supports extension \"hardlink@openssh.com\" revision 1\r\ndebug2: 
Server supports extension \"fsync@openssh.com\" revision 1\r\ndebug3: 
Sent message fd 6 T:16 I:1\r\ndebug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> 
/home/ansible size 0\r\nUnterminated quoted argument\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: 
Received exit status from master 0\r\n"}
fatal: [k4-test-2]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! failed 
to transfer file to /home/ansible/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-
1498045321.51-251782970755425/source:\nsftp> put 
'/home/goliath/k-systemd/annotation\n\nOpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-
4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016\r\ndebug1: Reading 
configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
line 19: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing 
master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: 
mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 1824\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug1:    
mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2\r\ndebug2: Remote 
version: 3\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension \"posix-
rename@openssh.com\" revision 1\r\ndebug2: Server supports extension 
\"statvfs@openssh.com\" revision 2\r\ndebug2: Server supports 
extension \"fstatvfs@openssh.com\" revision 2\r\ndebug2: Server 
supports extension \"hardlink@openssh.com\" revision 1\r\ndebug2: 
Server supports extension \"fsync@openssh.com\" revision 1\r\ndebug3: 
Sent message fd 6 T:16 I:1\r\ndebug3: SSH_FXP_REALPATH . -> 
/home/ansible size 0\r\nUnterminated quoted argument\r\ndebug3: 
mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: 
Received exit status from master 0\r\n"}
```

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью модуля `copy` можно копировать только единичные файлы.

Для копирования директорий, нужно использовать `synchronize`.